# Logstash Grok pattern for UserId

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I want create userId field with use of grok.
in log sample you can see [userId: id of user in guid format].
so what is the pattern need to add in grok for userId ? need some guidence for this.

here is my log

```
2020-10-15 16:01:29.1350 [84680] ERROR FinanceAPI.Controllers.TransactionController 192.168.43.244 Invalid Ledgers [UserId:1dfae3d2-258d-42d4-802e-c39a751574e3]
```

here is the grok pattern

```
grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{INT:processId}]\ %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logger} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{GREEDYDATA:message} }
            overwrite => "message"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`UUID` pattern should work to get the user id out of message.

[Here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/grok-patterns) is the default list of Grok pattens.

Comment: I did but it didn't happen

Comment: what is the output you get? and can you share how you added it ?

Comment: `match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{INT:processId}]\ %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logger} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{GREEDYDATA:message} \[%${UUID:UserId}]\"}`

Comment: there are few mistakes with the GROK. Not sure why you have `$` and you have not accounted for literal string `UserId`. Try this `match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{INT:processId}]\ %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{DATA:logger} %{IPV4:clientIp} %{GREEDYDATA:message} \[UserId:%{UUID:UserId}\]"}`